# Is there a python library which reflects html-css structure of the document so the information can be fed into scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, html-parsing

I am writing series of scrapy spiders which need to be taught how to parse the HTML document (with all the CSS tags etc.) All css tags however need to be analyzed manually. I was wondering if there would be a library which would compile information  on repeated html css tags etc and reveal what css/html tags should spider be looking for to extract particular information

Comment: I find it a bit hard to understand what you want. Maybe you could give a minimal example of what you want?

Comment: yes sure - so picture that I am writing a python scrapper with scrappy. In order for me to achieve this I would need to know what the structure of the page is (css classes, html tags etc.) preceding is in order to target scrapping only particular parts of the html pages. This structure is usually revealed through analysis of the html of the pages to be scrapped. What I want to have is a tool which will do the analysis for me so that I don't have to go in and manually look for css and html to write the scrapper.

Comment: And how much information about the desired data would you be specifying in code? What you are describing sounds like Scrapinghub’s [AutoExtract API](https://doc.scrapinghub.com/autoextract.html), but I’m not familiar with any Python library that does anything close.

Comment: @Gallaecio is there an open source library for the AutoExtract API you are talking about by any chance?

Comment: You can access the API with open source libraries, but the AutoExtract API itself is a paid service. I doubt there are free alternatives out there at the moment, but please do let me know if you find anything close to what you are looking for.l